# The number of ways to distribute hats between persons

Tags: combinatorics

By how many ways can we distribute 20 identical hats between 20 persons such that one person can take more than one hat ?

My attempt:-

Using the bars and stars method we get the number of ways is

$C^{39}_{20}$

Is this correct ?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: It should be $^{39}C_{19}$.

Comment: @Doubtnut That is the same as the OP's answer. Notice that $20+19=39$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was being too conformist with the formula $^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$ :-).